# Know if an HTTP request have been truncated

Tags: api, rest, http, security, axios

I wanted to know if there is a way to know if an HTTP request have been modified by a client (via burp suite for example).

I thought maybe with an integrity hash in the header, but I'm not sure if is the correct way to do that.

Example :

1. Client side (js) :

   ```js
   var fd = new FormData();
   fd.append("token", "ExampleToken");
   fd.append("email", "example@email.com");
   fd.append("subscription_level", 3);
   axios.post("https://urlToTheRestApi/file.php", fd).then(() => {
       //do some stuff
   })
   ```
2. Server side (php) :

   ```php
   //On server side, check if the data request has  not been modified by malicious user, then :

   if(isset($_POST['token']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['subscription_level']))
   {
       //do some stuff
   }
   ```

If you have examples how to do that i'm interested.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to make your question a [Minimum, reproducible example](/help/mcve). What kind of request is that, json, xml?

Comment: HTTPS ensures requests aren't tampered with.

Comment: [How and when do I use HMAC?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20129/how-and-when-do-i-use-hmac)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTPS prevents modification by intermediates. The only way the request could be modified when using HTTPS is if the user actively decided they want to modify their own request.

Fixing this is not really possible/reasonable. If the user controls the client, they can make the client do different things. If you feel you need this, you might need to solve your problem using a different approach.